# Controller not being registered as a service correctly?

Tags: php, symfony, symfony5, sylius

I am trying to create a basic EntryController controller with admin route in my Sylius/Symfony 5 setup.

My src/Controller/EntryController.php looks as follows:

```
<?php

namespace App\Controller;


use Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Controller\AbstractController;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Request;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Response;


class EntryController extends AbstractController
{

    /**
     * @param Request $request
     * @return Response
     */
    public function indexAction(Request $request): Response
    {
       dd('THIS CONTROLLER IS WORKING!');
    }

}
```

The route for my controller src/Resources/config/routing/admin/order_form.yml looks like the below:

```
sylius_complete_order_form:
  path: /order/form
  methods: [GET]
  controller: App\Controller\EntryController::index
```

And my controller is defined as a service inside config/services.yaml:

```
# Controllers are imported separately to make sure services can be injected
# as action arguments even if you don't extend any base controller class
App\Controller\:
    resource: '../src/Controller'
    public: true
    autowire: true
    tags: ['controller.service_arguments']
```

Currently when I try navigate to the path of the sylius_complete_order_form route defined above, I am getting the below error:

> "App\Controller\EntryController" has no container set, did you forget
> to define it as a service subscriber?

- I have tried manually clearing the cache by deleting var/cache
  folder.
- I have tried running `php bin/console cache:clear`
- When I run `php bin/console debug:container EntryController` the output is the below:

  ```
     Service ID       App\Controller\EntryController
     Class            App\Controller\EntryController
     Tags             controller.service_arguments
     Calls            setContainer
     Public           yes
     Synthetic        no
     Lazy             no
     Shared           yes
     Abstract         no
     Autowired        yes
     Autoconfigured   no
  ```

I don't understand why this is happening?

Any help or guidance would be greatly appreciated. Let me know should I need to include additional info.

Comment: Why do you want to register your own Controller as an Service?

Comment: The route is mapped to the controller service via the service id.  So change app.order_controller to App\Controller\OrderController in the service definition or change _controller: App\Controller\OrderController::index to _controller: app.order_controller::index.  I assume this is a legacy app being upgraded to Symfony 5?  Because there are easier ways to do this.  But it will work once you sort out the mapping.

Comment: As this is described as a Symfony 5 project I wonder why you want to register the controller as a service because normally the autowiring already should have loaded all classes of the project. Check your settings in services.yaml concering autowiring and autoconfiguring. Your controller class should extend AbstractController. I think because of this the request is not passed to your controller and the indexAction() which is expecting this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have managed to get my controller working by doing a few steps:

1. Remove the service definition of the EntryController from services.yaml
2. Extend AbstractController

class EntryController extends AbstractController

3. Enable autowire & make the controller public inside my services.yaml
   config/services.yaml

   App\Controller:
   resource: '../src/Controller'
   public: true
   autowire: true
   tags: ['controller.service_arguments']

Answer (score -2):

Your class has to extends "AbstractController" from "use Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Controller\AbstractController;"

You can check on the docs:

https://symfony.com/doc/current/controller.html#the-base-controller-class-services

(Usually, the default configuration is sufficient for your problem. You shouldn't need to touch it.)

By the way, if you change the conf, don't forget to clear the cache,just to be sure.

Tell me if it's working!

Comment: Well no.  It is common to extend from AbstractController but it is certainly not required.  Many people just inject whatever dependency(s) then need directly into a controller class.  The real problems in this question deal with how the controller is configured as a service.  Coupled with the fact that the OP has not yet responded.  I suppose you could update your answer with the details needed for an actual solution.  Or just consider deleting it.

Comment: "Your class has to extends" - why? Please add some explanation to your answer such that others can learn from it